# Need to go under height / 2 with cursor

Tags: c#, cursor, position

I got a cursor problem. I need the cursor to point at the "Enter game" button, and it is below windowHeight / 2, and over windowHeight / 1. And when I put 1.5, it says "Cannot convert to float". So what should I do?

(Don't say I should add +50, because it's different on different resolutions).

Comment: lol, sorry, but i dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor position cannot be a float, so try to cast it to an int

```
(int)(windowHeight / 1.5)
```

Comment: It says "Cannot convert double to int".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, Convert.ToInt32(double_value)

```
Convert.ToInt32(windowHeight / 1.5)
```

HTH